# MDX query for bottomcount function

Tags: ssas, mdx

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS
 ,BottomCount
  (
    NonEmpty([Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS)
   ,10
   ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2005];
```

The above query is showing me result having last 10 customer names with NULL measure value. I am using Adventure works Cube.

As per my understanding "bottomcount" is not working fine with where clause in "mdx" query. I want to fetch last 10 customer names for 2005 with measure value and hopefully i am looking for solution without using keyword "DESCENDANTS".

Please let me know in case, I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
bottomcount(
    nonempty(
        [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].Members
        ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    )
    ,10
    ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
)
```

You were getting the Customer names with NULL because in OLAP you are doing the cartesian product between the 2 dimensions (Measures is a special dimension, but it still acts as a dimension) it does not matter that you don't have values it will still crossjoin the members in your 2 sets and unless you request just the nonempty ones it will still give you the NULLs.

Comment: Thanks @mxix  for your answer. It would be really very grateful to you if you can give me the reason why i was getting  customer names with NULL measure value in my mdx query or can suggest me an article related to this.

Answer (score 1):

And if you'd like their full internet sales amount then move some of the logic into the `WITH` clause:

```
WITH 
  SET bot AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
      [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
     ,(
        [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
       ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2005]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS
 ,BottomCount
  (
    bot
   ,10
   ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Thanks @whytheq  for your answer. I am getting different result from your query and with the query provided by mxix(in above). I just want to validate the same with you.

Comment: Mine returns - all customers who had internetsales amounts in 2005 > find the bottom 10 of these > then return the _total_ internet sales amount for those 10 customers .... so it will show the lifetime sales amount for each of the lowest 10 customers in 2005

Comment: thany you @whytheq. Now i got the point. I really appreciate your answer.